# TinyMCE with Bootstrap not showing in editor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tinymce, tinymce-5

With a clean TinyMCE 5 install and bootstrap the editor doesn't show the bootstrap styles as you edit.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my current setup:

```
var useDarkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;

tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#mytextarea',
  plugins: 'print preview paste importcss searchreplace autolink autosave save directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount imagetools textpattern noneditable help charmap quickbars emoticons',
  imagetools_cors_hosts: ['ewiadmin.s3.amazonaws.com'],
  menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
  toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist | forecolor backcolor removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | fullscreen  preview save print | insertfile image media template link anchor codesample | ltr rtl',
  toolbar_sticky: true,
  autosave_ask_before_unload: true,
  autosave_interval: '30s',
  autosave_prefix: '{path}{query}-{id}-',
  autosave_restore_when_empty: false,
  autosave_retention: '2m',
  image_advtab: true,
  link_list: [
    { title: 'MVN', value: 'Removed for stack'}
  ],
  image_list: [
    { title: 'NVM', value: 'removed for stack' }
  ],
  image_class_list: [
    { title: 'None', value: '' },
    { title: 'Some class', value: 'class-name' }
  ],
  importcss_append: true,
  file_picker_callback: function (callback, value, meta) {
    /* Provide file and text for the link dialog */
    if (meta.filetype === 'file') {
      callback('https://www.google.com/logos/google.jpg', { text: 'My text' });
    }

    /* Provide image and alt text for the image dialog */
    if (meta.filetype === 'image') {
      callback('https://www.google.com/logos/google.jpg', { alt: 'My alt text' });
    }

    /* Provide alternative source and posted for the media dialog */
    if (meta.filetype === 'media') {
      callback('movie.mp4', { source2: 'alt.ogg', poster: 'https://www.google.com/logos/google.jpg' });
    }
  },
  templates: [
    { title: 'Responsive Columns (2)', description: 'Creates columns that will automatically turn into a single column when viewed on smaller devices like phones.', content: '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6">Column 1</div><div class="col-md-6">Column 2</div></div>' },
    { title: 'Starting my story', description: 'A cure for writers block', content: 'Once upon a time...' },
    { title: 'New list with dates', description: 'New List with dates', content: '<div class="mceTmpl"><span class="cdate">cdate</span><br /><span class="mdate">mdate</span><h2>My List</h2><ul><li></li><li></li></ul></div>' }
  ],
  template_cdate_format: '[Date Created (CDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S]',
  template_mdate_format: '[Date Modified (MDATE): %m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S]',
  height: 600,
  image_caption: true,
  quickbars_selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote quickimage quicktable',
  noneditable_noneditable_class: 'mceNonEditable',
  toolbar_mode: 'sliding',
  contextmenu: 'link image imagetools table',
  skin: useDarkMode ? 'oxide-dark' : 'oxide',
  content_css: useDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'default',
  content_style: 'body {font-size:14px }'
 });
```

You can see I added a template for columns, but I also tested buttons.

Here are some attached screenshots of what happens when I'm trying

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want TinyMCE to style bootstrap elements you need to pass the Bootstrap CSS to the editor itself via `content_css`.  Here is a simple example:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/d6haab

In specific please note the inclusion of this configuration option:

```
content_css: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

...this is what passes the Bootstrap CSS to the editor's content that exists inside the TinyMCE iframe.